# Intercept cookie with NGINX from upstream response and create a new cookie

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

In order to synchronize two web applications, I need to intercept KEYCLOAK_SESSION cookie with NGINX from upstream response - sso.example.com and if such cookie is present, create another cookie SID (copy of KEYCLOAK_SESSION ) but for .example.com domain.

Is it possible with NGINX and if so, could you please show NGINX configuration for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When the response from the upstream to NGINX contains the KEYCLOAK_SESSION cookie, I need to create a brand new cookie with the name SID. This new cookie should have the same max-age as the KEYCLOAK_SESSION cookie but a different domain.

Comment: Also, the value in the SID cookie may be just a simple '1'.

Comment: I'm going to use the SID cookie as a flag for my application to determine whether there is an active Single Sign-On session. I don't want to use this cookie as the session itself; it's merely a flag to trigger additional application-specific actions.

Comment: please update the question and details, if you want have a clue like [ask] clean up the commentary after updating the question

Comment: Thanks :) It seems like StackExchange is becoming increasingly less useful